# std::forward vs std::move while binding lvalue to rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11

is there a difference between move and forward here:

```
void test(int && val)
{
    val=4;
}

void main()
{  
    int nb;
    test(std::forward<int>(nb));
    test(std::move(nb));
    std::cin.ignore();    
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your specific case, no, there isn't any difference.

Detailed answer:

Under the hood, `std::move(t)` does `static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)`, where `T` is type of `t` (see §20.2.3/6). In your case, it resolves to `static_cast<int&&>(nb)`.

`forward` is a little bit tricky, because it is tailored for use in templates (to allow perfect forwarding) and not as a tool to cast lvalue to rvalue reference.

Standard library provides two overloads (one for lvalue references and the second for rvalue ones, see §20.2.3/2):

```
template <class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type& t) noexcept;
template <class T> T&& forward(typename remove_reference<T>::type&& t) noexcept;
```

Substituting `int`, we get:

```
int&& forward(int& t) noexcept;
int&& forward(int&& t) noexcept;
```

And since `nb` is lvalue, the first version is chosen. According to standard draft, the only effect of `forward` is `static_cast<T&&>(t)`. With `T` being `int`, we get `static_cast<int&&>(nb)`, i.e. - we get two exactly same casts.

Now, if you want to cast lvalue to rvalue (to allow moving), please use only `std::move`, which is the idiomatic way to do this conversion. `std::forward` is not intended to be used this way.

Answer (score 2):

No difference.

---